# What is the email address format "Name <email>" called?

Tags: email, terminology, standards

Given an email address in the format

```
John Doe <john@example.com>
```

I wonder where this format is explicitly defined and what the whole thing is called. <strike>It doesn't seem to be specified in</strike> [rfc5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) (at least I didn't find it). So given the address above, what would you name the following member variables if you had to define a class for it?

- `John Doe` (name)
- `john@example.com>` (address)
- `John Doe <john@example.com>` -> what do you call the whole thing?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

#### John Doe <john@example.com> → what do you call the whole thing?

It's called a mailbox, as specified in RFC 5322 on page 45:

**3.4.  Address Specification**

> Addresses occur in several message header fields to indicate senders
> and recipients of messages.  An address may either be an individual
> mailbox, or a group of mailboxes.

> Normally, a mailbox is composed of two parts: (1) an optional display
> name that indicates the name of the recipient (which can be a person
> or a system) that could be displayed to the user of a mail
> application, and (2) an addr-spec address enclosed in angle brackets
> ("<" and ">").  There is an alternate simple form of a mailbox where
> the addr-spec address appears alone, without the recipient's name or
> the angle brackets.  The Internet addr-spec address is described in
> section 3.4.1.

Source [3.4.  Address Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4)

See also [Appendix A.1.2.  Different Types of Mailboxes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#appendix-A.1.2)

Comment: *picardfacepalm*

Comment: I think the name must be in quotes: `"John Doe" <john@example.com>`

Comment: @i486 Quotes are not required. See the examples in the RFC (second link in my answer).

Comment: @DavidPostill See 3.2.1 and 3.2.4.

Comment: @i486 Quotes are only required if the name contains non-`atom` characters (with `.` special cased). E.g. a `,` makes quotes neccessary.
See 3.2.5 and 4.1.

Comment: @i486 see my answer. A part in question is a `display-name`, which is a `phrase` according to 3.4; `phrase` is defined in 3.2.5 as a word as *either* `atom` *or* a `quoted-string`. I.e. it is possible for it to *not to be* a `quoted-string`.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I agree that quotes are redundant in most cases. But they will be OK even if not necessary. Instead of analyzing whether quotes are necessary or not, they can be used every time (I think some email clients do it).

Comment: You're wrong. Without quotes a display-name value becomes just `John Doe`. With quotes we have an ambigious case: parser has no way to tell if it must go quoted string route or include quotes into the term value like this: `"John Doe"`. And I know that different parsers do it differently. So, to be sure how it will be parsed, you *should not* use quotes if it's not syntactically necessary. Never use it as a kind of "safeguard", it is not designed to be used for that. Also "@i486", please note, how using other's names "in quotes" feels like sarcasm. I prefer others don't use them for me.

Answer (score 45):

It is in the [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4), you just missed it:

```
address         =   mailbox / group
mailbox         =   name-addr / addr-spec
name-addr       =   [display-name] angle-addr
angle-addr      =   [CFWS] "<" addr-spec ">" [CFWS] / obs-angle-addr
group           =   display-name ":" [group-list] ";" [CFWS]
display-name    =   phrase
mailbox-list    =   (mailbox *("," mailbox)) / obs-mbox-list
address-list    =   (address *("," address)) / obs-addr-list
group-list      =   mailbox-list / CFWS / obs-group-list
```

Let's break this down.

`address` either a `mailbox` or a `group`. A `mailbox` is a `name-addr` or `addr-spec`.

This `name-addr` is the format you're asking about: there is an optional `display-name` (it's optional because it is defined with square brackets) followed by the `angle-addr`, which itself is an `addr-spec` in angle brackets with optional foldable space `CFWS` on both sides of it (defined further in the [section 3.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.2)), or an obsolete address format `obs-angle-addr`.

A whole [section 3.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1) is dedicated to the description of `addr-spec` format.

So, in conclusion:

- `John Doe <john@example.com>` is a `name-addr`, which is a variant of `mailbox`, which is a variant of `address`.
- `John Doe` is a `display-name`
- `<john@example.com>` is an `angle-addr`
- `john@example.com` is an `addr-spec`
- `john` is a `local-part`
- `example.com` is a `domain`.